# Laravel 5 redirect when not login using Entrust

Tags: php, laravel

I need to move a user is not logged on to the site where it will be able to log in.

So far I have tried methods such as:

```
Entrust::routeNeedsRole('admin/advanced*', 'owner', Redirect::to('/home'));
```

And other but these methods do not work and I get error like this:

```
Method filter does not exist.
```

my routes.php file looks like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['permission:admin']], function () {

    Route::get('/admin', 'DashboardController@index');
});
```

And this method work fine but when I'm not logged  I get error:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
HttpException in Application.php line 905:
```

Controller

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

Comment: I had some similar problems with when using `Entrust::routeNeeds...`, so I switched to using only middlewares. Make sure you have the auth middleware before checking for permission and/or role `['middleware' => ['auth', 'permission:admin']]`. Not sure if this error is incompatible with Laravel versions or some bug.

Comment: I use the latest versions of laravel and entrust. Can you tell me more or write a piece of code, because still don't know what to do it.

Comment: Do this `['middleware' => ['auth', 'permission:admin']]` - here you check for **auth** before permission, so you'll have a logged user. And avoid using the entrust facade `Entrust::...`.

Comment: only that I want to redirect logged to the login page. I still do not understand :(

Comment: Why redirect **logged** to login page?

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake. A person who is not logged in and attempt to enter "localhost/blog/public/a" will be redirected to "localhost/blog/public/login-page"

Comment: The **auth** middleware will redirect a guest user to **login** URL and make a virtual host don't access the app like this *localhost/blog/public*.

Comment: I added to questions my controller.

Comment: I tried everything and when I am not logged gets an error Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.   AND : NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: